# statistics on proportion wise data

Tags: proportion

What are the usual statistical procedures used for data that is in proportions ? I have data about survival proportions of two species across 7 elevations .. What statistical tests could I run apart from regression on proportions across the 7 elevations ?

Comment: If you don't fancy a model specifically designed for regressing proportions on things, then you should at least transform them.  In the absence of zeros, *logits* will behave much better in a regular linear regression setup, whilst not being much harder to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

With large sample sizes, proportion data approximates the binomial distribution, so you should be able to do logistic regression.

There's a good review on inference with proportion data from [Joseph & Reinhold](http://www.ajronline.org/content/184/4/1057.full), if you want to get a general overview of the techniques!